# CS:GO получить сылку на файл .dem

Tags: php, node.js, steam-web-api

Нужно получить ссылку файл в формате .dem по коду демо (как пример код `CSGO-OyjY3-pPKCF-cmpHJ-wdohh-CY5dK`)

Нужная ссылка выглядит так `http://replay124.valve.net/730/003072985384448163905_0699089210.dem.bz2`
, но как по коду  демо получить значения:

1. `003072985384448163905`
2. `0699089210`
3. `124`

Хотелось бы сделать на PHP но можно и на NodeJS, но не нашёл ничего на эту тему в интернете.

Up:
 В самой игре демо можно скачать по внутреней консоли игры командой `csgo_download_match код демо` например `csgo_download_match CSGO-pj5MV-zyzpa-PaHVb-tFUwV-HGXbD`, но всеравно как оно расшифровывет в ссылку остаётся загадкой

Comment: Полагаю что в документации это все написано: https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/api
WebAPI: https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/webapi

Comment: Да вот дело  в том что у Steam нету нужных методов, но можно же реализовать и без API, сама игра же как-то получает ссылку, но как..

Comment: Для этого и существует API, в котором реализована вся логика создания этих ссылок. Полная документация по API доступна после регистрации, так там написано.

Comment: Это не то, я вошёл почитал, я так понял тут документация по интегрированию Steam в игры, но я же не создаю игру

Comment: Скорее всего идёт запрос на сервер стима с этим кодом, а в ответ ссылка на файл демо. Снифай пакеты. Посмотри откуда берётся код демо, кто его генерирует.

Comment: Да вот сниффером не сильно умею пользовался но HTTP запросы отслеживать умею сылку на демо получал через сниффер но дело в том что кроме как запроса на скачку не нашел ничего p.s юзаю Wireshark Network analyzer

Comment: Уточню сылку на саму демо получил только через снифер когда скачиваю демо по её коду (в игре) а вот сам код можно получить (именно код не сылку) в разделе смотреть -> мои матчи (в самой игре)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ваша проблема уже решена, более того, есть библиотека для nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/csgo А вот и код, который расшифровывает ваш код:

```
var scDecoder = new csgo.SharecodeDecoder("CSGO-U6MWi-hYFWJ-opPwD-JciHm-qOijD");
console.log(scDecoder.decode());
```

В репе есть более полный пример, используйте его.

--

Внутриигровой загрузчик использует функцию CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_MatchListRequestFullGameInfo из внутренней библиотеки NetHook2.dll

UPD: Вот метод,который использует эти функции, даже называется также https://github.com/joshuaferrara/node-csgo/blob/master/handlers/match.js#L77

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, при decode получается вот такой объект `{ matchId: '3147867909473173539', outcomeId: '3147871371216814391',tokenId: '8483' }` но что делать с этими значениями? как ни пробовал подставлять не качает демо

Comment: @Red Woolf посмотрите примеры использования библиотеки, наверняка сайты её используют.

Comment: Да вот дело в том что сайты используют но документации норм не найти в обще, только то что на github и npmjs и больше примеров не найти

Comment: Делаю так `var Steam = require('steam'),
    steamClient = new Steam.SteamClient(),
    steamUser = new Steam.SteamUser(steamClient),
    steamGC = new Steam.SteamGameCoordinator(steamClient, 730),
    csgo = require('csgo'),
    CSGO = new csgo.CSGOClient(steamUser, steamGC, false);

var scDecoder = new csgo.SharecodeDecoder("CSGO-OXDfo-2Lnfv-YFFhM-qhUfR-awkMC");
var ob = scDecoder.decode();
console.log(CSGO.requestGame(ob.matchId, ob.outcomeId, ob.tokenId));`  но возвращает null

Comment: `callback` забыли же в методе `CSGO.requestGame`

Comment: На npmjs не было указано что callback, но сейчас прописал с callback но нечего просто не возвращает

Comment: Откройте issue в репе библиотеки и спросите у автора. Либо сами покопайте исходный код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41233/discussion-between-red-woolf-and-reklatsmasters).

Answer (score 1):

Можно поглядеть тут (c#)
Функция generatematchlist
https://github.com/akiver/CSGO-Demos-Manager/blob/04b44968a4d3c70664e1b3c85c93f5e68ca9a5d2/src/ViewModel/HomeViewModel.cs

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я в c# не бум бум, функцию (вызов) там вроде GenerateMatchListFile но откуда там её тянет незнаю

Comment: Интересный проект не проверял его работает или нет, но метод отвечающий за формирование URL точно не `generatematchlist`, он всего лишь возвращает параметр для условия. А вот метод `GetDemoListUrl()` похоже возвращает как раз то, что нам нужно (список текущих URL) https://github.com/akiver/CSGO-Demos-Manager/blob/04b44968a4d3c70664e1b3c85c93f5e68ca9a5d2/src/Services/DemosService.cs В нём же `GetMatchListDataFilePath()` формирует нужный патч

Answer (score -2):

Ну кто так задаёт вопросы?! Какую именно ссылку нужно создать? 
Но, если как я понимаю, нужно отдать файл по определенному запросу, то примерно так когда то давно делал.

```
if($_GET['code'] == 'CSGO-OyjY3-pPKCF-cmpHJ-wdohh-CY5dK') {
    Header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    Header("Connection: close");
    Header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    Header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    Header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=new_filename.pdf");
    Header("Content-Length: 50000");

    readfile('test_file.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Есть игра в Steam CS:GO в ней записываются игры на сервера steam а в последних играх  к кажодой игре указан код по которому можно скачать демо или дать другу что бы скачать и по какому-то алгоритму можно получить ссылку (есть сайты на которых это реализовано но как реализовать я не знаю вот и спрашиваю